# How to show consistency and asymptotic normality of estimators from solving an estimating equation?

Tags: asymptotics, consistency

Estimating equation is another way to obtain estimators when likelihood can not be written out explicitly. Generally we will solve a set of estimating equation. And the estimators are consistent and asymptotically normal. Here are three questions.

1. How can we make sure solutions exist?
2. How to show the consistency of estimators?
3. How to show the asymptotical normality of the estimators?

I was hoping some people know the papers dealing with the theory of estimating equations and deriving those things. Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: Generally you would try to mimic what you do for maximum likelihood  estimators.